# Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (257, 257) but got array with shape (257, 1)

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, lstm, dimensions

```
print(X.shape,Y.shape)
#(5877, 257, 1) (5877, 257, 1)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(257, input_shape=(257,1),stateful=False,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(257, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss=losses.mean_squared_error, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x=X,y=Y,epochs=100,shuffle=False)
```

> Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (257, 257) but got array with shape (257, 1)

I should give `5877 frames of size 257` to lstm layer. The output has the same format. Where I was mistaken?

Comment: maybe here `input_shape=(257,1)` you need to put `input_shape=(257,257)` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no(

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848107/error-in-fitting-an-rnn-lstm-model/50851822#50851822

Comment: The fix will depend on what you are trying to achieve. What's objective here? What are you trying to predict given what?

Comment: I want to predict real noise signal rate (nsr) by nsr obtained by postfilter. It's way to improve it.